# Browserstack + webdriverio OS parallel config

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, browserstack

I have a series of test suites that need to be run in both Mac OS and Windows OS. Each OS will also need to run the tests on Chrome, Firefox,  Safari || IE.  I have parallel testing setup for browsers but can't figure out the best way to do incorporate the OS flag into this.

Currently I am doing the following to build my capabilities for browser testing.

```
...
    commonCapabilities: {
      'project': 'Bond',
      'name': 'James Bond',
    },

    capabilities: [{
      browser: 'chrome'
    }, {
      browser: 'firefox'
    }, {
      browser: 'internet explorer'
    }, {
      browser: 'safari'
    }],
...
```

exporting them here:

```
exports.config.capabilities.forEach(function (caps) {
  for (var i in exports.config.commonCapabilities) caps[i] = caps[i] || exports.config.commonCapabilities[i];
});
```

What I am hoping to accomplish is something like this:

```
...
    commonCapabilities: {
      'project': 'Bond',
      'name': 'James Bond',
    },

    osCapabilities: [{
        os: 'Windows',
        os_version: '10',
    }, {
        os: 'OS X',
        os_version: 'Mojave',
    }]

    browserCapabilities: [{
      browser: 'chrome'
    }, {
      browser: 'firefox'
    }, {
      browser: 'internet explorer'
    }, {
      browser: 'safari'
    }],
...
```

which would then test each browser in each OS with my commonCapabilities.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround to this, you could create two separate files for Windows and Mac OS as below-

1. parallelWin.conf.json
2. parallelMac.conf.json

After creating separate files, you will need to add the details in the [package.json](https://github.com/browserstack/webdriverio-browserstack/blob/master/package.json) file as below-

For Windows -

```
"parallelWin": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio conf/parallelWin.conf.js"
```

For Mac -

```
"parallelMac": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio conf/parallelMac.conf.js"
```

Now to run [BrowserStack's WebdriverIO](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/webdriverio) sample run the below commands-

1. For Windows - 
   **npm run parallelWin**
2. For Mac - 
   **npm run parallelMac**